# Sequence in an array

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm

I have an algo exercise to do and I have no idea how to do it, as the requirement is to use only basic programming concepts. So - the point is to find the longest sequence of numbers in an array that are growing or not changing value.

So for the array [1,1,2,4,0,1,7,4], it would be [1,1,2,4].

It should have as small time and memory complexity as possible. Any solutions, tips? Much love and thanks in advance for any advice or feedback.

That's what I've managed to do in the last 10 minutes, but I feel like I'm doing it in the most complex way possible...

```
function idk(array) {
  
  var current = 0;
  var winner = 0;

  var currentArray = [];
  var winnerArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {

    if (array[i + 1] >= array[i]) {

      currentArray.push(array[i]);
      current = currentArray.length;

    } else {

      currentArray.push(array[i]);

      if (currentArray.length > best.length) {

        // copy array and append it to the new array?

      }

    }

    }
    return winnerArray;
  }
```

Comment: why python and genetic-algorithm tags? have you tried something?

Comment: Becouse it's an algorithm. I usually do it in the python and js, so I've choosen these tags.

Comment: This is a fairly basic algorithm. Iterate through the array until you find a value that's not consecutive, and push the resulting numbers to a results array. Then continue from the last index, iterate until you find a value that's not consecutive etc., until you reach the end of the array. Then pick the result that's the longest. If you wanna be extra cool, google for the two pointers technique.

Comment: You aren't going to be well received here simply dumping what appears to be a homework assignment and looking for someone to do the entire thing for you. (You may get an answer that does just that looking for rep though). But generally you should post what you tried, what went wrong, and things you tried to resolve that problem.

That being said, is there a site for helping people with homework that we can post on these types of questions?

Comment: This is a classic dynamic programming first exercise. Is that what your assignment is about?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I will post my try then! I'm quite new so I don't know much about "community rules" here.

Comment: Did you test this? Because it looks like the array would go out of bounds.

Comment: Yes @pakpe, I've just started doing algorithms. Before uni I was just programming backend in Nodejs and Express, so I don't know much about algorithms and all of these things. I feel like I started programming from the wrong side, lol.

Comment: @ngr900 Well I'm already sure that's an overkill for such a type of exercise so I just stopped here, becouse I don't know how to do it in the simplier way (that's why am here basically)

Comment: I actually don't think your code is overkill, it looks like you are on the right path to be honest.

Comment: I mean just run it with any known input and see if it returns the correct result. You're iterating to `i <= array.length`, so the last loop will try to access `array[array.length]`, which is out of bounds and will throw an error.  In fact, you're accessing `array[i + 1]` so an error will be thrown on the penultimate loop.

Comment: Really, thanks a lot guys. So I think now I'm going to continue, someone posted a good solution below but I want to understand what's happening. If I'm on the good path, thanks for help then, I will try to move it forward. It's my first exercise so I'm quite disorientated.

Comment: I can post the dynamic algorithm in python. Here is a hint: you create a second array  L of the same length and populate it with zeroes . L will store the largest possible length for a sub array that starts at that index. The base case is the last element in L which has a value of 1. You starts at the last element and iterate backward with 2 nested loops. The outer loop goes backward through L and the inner loop goes forward from each index to the end.

Comment: @pakpe - it sound really good, but the point is to have max. 2 loops I think - as the time complexity must be at the lowest level possible - so the whole algorithm should be done in the simpliest way possible (that's at least how I understand it).

Comment: Does your sequences correspond to consecutive elements or not?

Comment: The code I gave you has two loops (nested). It has the minimum time complexity for this problem.

Comment: @pakpe OP seems to ask for consecutive elements as `[1,1,2,4,7]` would be the example solution otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript algorithm:

```js
var array = [1, 8, 1, 1, 5, 7, 2, 2]
var output = []
array.forEach(function(value, index) {
  if (array[index - 1] <= value && index != 0) {
    output[output.length - 1].push(value)
  } else {
    output.push([value])
  }
})
var longestArray = []
output.forEach(function(arrayCompare, index) {
  if (arrayCompare.length > longestArray.length || index == 0) {
    longestArray = arrayCompare
  }
})
console.log(longestArray)
```

The first `forEach` loops through the elements of `array`. If the element is larger than or equal to the previous element, it adds it to the last array *in* `output`. If it is not, then it creates a new array, and pushes the array into `output`. This creates arrays with "growing" sequences.

After that, it loops through each sequence, and checks if the length of the sequence is greater than the current longest sequence, which is stored in `longestArray`. If it is, it changes `longestArray` to that. If it isn't, it does nothing.

Note that both of these loops have exceptions if the index is `0`, since there is no element with index `-1` (therefore such an exception had to be made).

Also, here's the same implementation in python:

```
array = [1, 8, 1, 1, 5, 7, 2, 2]
output = []

index = 0
while index < len(array):
  value = array[index]
  if (array[index-1] <= value and index !=0):
    output[-1].append(value)
  else:
    output.append([value])
  index += 1

longestArray = []
index = 0
while index < len(output):
  arrayCompare = output[index]
  if index==0 or len(arrayCompare) > len(longestArray):
    longestArray = arrayCompare
  index += 1

print(longestArray)
```

Comment: It seem to work, can you explain me how is it working in general?

Comment: Just edited it! I was actually just doing that :), and after clicking Save Edits, I saw your comment.

Comment: Jesus, thanks so much for the help! Now I finally feel that I got it and I was on the right path, I guess I should be patient next time. Again - thanks for help. I would give you an arrow up but I can't do it for now, unfortunately..

Comment: I updated my code to be a bit more efficient, and included an algorithm for python too, since you tagged your question python as well as javascript, indicating that you were looking for a general algorithm concept, but I wasn't sure which one was better for your usage.

Answer (score 0):

Just why loop over the end of the array?

Because you could take this advantage to gather the last longest sequence without having a check after the loop for having found a longest sequence.

But in parts:

Why not a temporary array? Because there is no need to use it, if you collect the values. the startignn index of a sequence is important and the actual indec to decide if the sequence is longer then the previously found one.

The loop feature two conditions, one for continuing the loop, if in sequence and another to check if the actual ended sequence is longer. And for storing the actual index.

The last loop with a check for an undefined value is `false`, it does not continue the loop and the nect check reveals either a new longest sequence or not.

Some other annotation:

- `winnerArray` has to be an empty array, because of the check later for `length`
- The sequence check take the previous element, because the loop starts with the first index and the previous element is given.
- The [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is O(n).

```js
function idk(array) {
    let winnerArray = [],
        index = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i < array.length + 1; i++) {
        if (array[i - 1] <= array[i]) continue;
        if (i - index > winnerArray.length) winnerArray = array.slice(index, i);
        index = i;
    }
    return winnerArray;
}

console.log(...idk([1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 7, 4])); // [1, 1, 2, 4]
console.log(...idk([1, 8, 1, 1, 5, 7, 2, 2])); // [1, 1, 5, 7]
console.log(...idk([1, 8, 1, 1, 5, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dynamic programming algorithm in Python:

```
def longest_sequence(numbers):
    length = len(numbers)
    L = [0] * length #L stores max possible lengths at each index
    L[-1] = 1 # base case
    for i in range(length-2, -1, -1):
        max_length = L[i]
        for j in range(i, length):
            if (L[j] > max_length) and (numbers[j] > numbers[i]):
                max_length = L[j]
        L[i] = max_length + 1

    #trace back
    max_length = max(L)
    result = []
    for k in range(max_length, 0, -1):
        result.append(numbers[L.index(k)])
        numbers = numbers[L.index(k):]
        L = L[L.index(k):]
    return result

my_numbers = [36,13,78,85,16,52,58,61,63,83,46,19,85,1,58,71,26,26,21,31]
print(longest_sequence(my_numbers))
#>>[13, 16, 52, 58, 61, 63, 83, 85]
```

Answer (score 0):

To be optimal, you should not use intermediate lists during processing.  You only need to hold indexes, sizes and the previous value:

```
def longSeq(A):
    longStart,longSize = 0,0       # best range so far (index and size only)
    start,size,prev    = 0,0,None  # current range (index and size)
    for i,a in enumerate(A):
        if i == 0 or prev <= a:    # increase current range
            size += 1
            prev  = a
            if size > longSize:    # track longest so far
                longStart,longSize = start,size
        else:            
            start,size,prev = i,1,a # sequence break, restart current
    return A[longStart:longStart+longSize]
```

output:

```
print(longSeq([1,1,2,4,0,1,7,4]))  # [1, 1, 2, 4]
print(longSeq( [1,8,1,1,5,7,2,2])) # [1, 1, 5, 7]
```

This will perform in O(n) time and use O(1) space.

Comment: Recommend add ```` if not A: return []```` at beginning